# External clients get a certificate mismatch - but internal clients do not

Tags: iis, ssl, ssl-certificate, https, certificate

I have a scenario where external clients are receiving a certificate that is different than the one that is bound to the IIS site.  This is Win2008R2 / IIS, in the following configuration:

(interwebs) -- > (LB) --> (IIS reverse-proxy/DMZ) --> (IIS www hosting 2 separate sites each with unique FQDN, unique IP, & unique SSL EV)

There is no cert on the LB. There are no certs on the IIS rev proxy (its just an HTTP redirect / URL-rewrite)

The IIS server has (2) sites configured, each with its own unique FQDN, and corresponding SSL EV cert bound to a unique IP on the server. E.g.

- physical IP = 1.1.1.1

  - virtual-ip1 = 1.1.1.2
  - virtual-ip2 = 1.1.1.3
- app.abc.com = 1.1.1.2
- app.xyz.com = 1.1.13

Currently, clients get the correct cert when reaching `app.abc.com`, but when going to `app.xyz.com`, they get an SSL cert error about name mismatch, where the FQDN doesn't match the common name. I've verified when on the IIS server, the certs FQDN and common name/issued to matches what it should be.

WHERE is this cert coming from? If I were to run packet-capture on say, the client, the IIS server, where would you think the cert will show from when filtering SSL traffic?

(apologies if this is missing information)

Comment: If the Common Name in the certificate subject is `app.abc.com` and external clients need to browse `app.xyz.com`, of course they are going to get a name mismatch error. The browser is literally saying: "app.abc.com" is not the same as "app.xyz.com" - which is entirely correct.

Comment: `clients get the correct cert when reaching app.abc.com, but when going to app.xyz.com, they get an SSL cert error about name mismatch` - Of course they do.